# select X subcategories and N items for each subcategorie mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, records

I have three tables

```
site_article | site_famille_articles | site_categorie
id           | id                    | id
titre        | titre                 | titre
famille_id   | categorie_id
```

famille_id is constraint key to site_famille_articles
categorie_idis constraint key to site_categorie

in my website, I want to display 4 at most 'site_famille_articles' items per page and display 6 at most 'site_article' items for each 'site_famille_articles' for the selected 'site_categorie'

I hope I arrive to explain my problem

is there any way to do that in mysql

here is what I tried

```
$table_categorie = "site_categorie";
$table_famille_articles = "site_famille_articles";
$table_article = "site_article";

$sql = "SELECT $table_article.id as article_id, 
                $table_article.titre as article_titre, 
                $table_famille_articles.titre as famille_titre
                FROM $table_article 
                LEFT JOIN $table_famille_articles on $table_article.famille_id = $table_famille_articles.id 
                LEFT JOIN $table_categorie on $table_famille_articles.categorie_id = $table_categorie.id 
                WHERE $table_categorie.id IN 
                        ( SELECT id FROM $table_categorie WHERE $table_categorie.titre like '%".$_POST['titre_categorie']."%' )
                ORDER BY famille_titre ASC"
```

this query allow me to have all 'site_article'  items grouped by 'site_famille_articles' for the selected 'site_categorie'

here is an example : 
this query :

```
SELECT site_article.id as article_id, site_article.titre as article_titre, site_famille_articles.titre as famille_titre FROM site_article LEFT JOIN site_famille_articles on site_article.famille_id = site_famille_articles.id LEFT JOIN site_categorie on site_famille_articles.categorie_id = site_categorie.id WHERE site_categorie.id IN ( SELECT id FROM site_categorie WHERE site_categorie.titre like 'Peinture' ) ORDER BY famille_titre ASC
```

give me this result : [image](http://s2.postimg.org/bcezulw7d/reco.png)

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I'm sure this can be done, but it would be much easier to do with some sample data, or an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) if you can make one.

Comment: please see the example I added in post @McAdam331

Comment: Okay. And what is wrong with the data you have, what do you expect to see instead?

Comment: and I want to have two variables : max number of 'site_article' for each 'site_famille_articles' and max number of 'site_famille_articles', have you understand ?

Comment: I do understand, and I have an idea but it will be hard to test. I will write it as an answer anyways.

Comment: I want to have only N records for each 'site_famille_articles'